# Remote MYSQL on jasperreports error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports, tomcat7, jasperserver

I am trying to use a remote MYSQL source for my jasperserver.  The connection is good and does not throw an error. However, when I try to make a report in jasperstudio, I get the following error

Error log:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.getConnection(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:166)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:126)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.jdbc.JDBCFieldsProvider.getFields(JDBCFieldsProvider.java:52)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.jdbc.JDBCDataAdapterDescriptor.getFields(JDBCDataAdapterDescriptor.java:83)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.ui.SimpleQueryWizardDataEditorComposite.readFields(SimpleQueryWizardDataEditorComposite.java:258)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.property.dataset.wizard.WizardDataSourcePage.run(WizardDataSourcePage.java:369)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.wizards.JSSWizardRunnablePage$1.run(JSSWizardRunnablePage.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:175)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.getConnection(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:141)
    ... 7 more
```

I absolutely have the driver class `mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar` in `/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0/lib` too.

I also have the same connector.jar in the class path /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/lib ... still nothing.

I'm not sure what the problem is...any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is `/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0/lib` on the classpath?

Comment: hmm...i'm not sure. I'm guessing i'd find that in apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver ? Do you know exactly where?

Comment: I found it...it is in /webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/lib I put the connector.jar in there too but it still throws the same error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED IT!!

I had to add the driver to the class path in jasper suite too!

Comment: Silly question: How does one add the driver to the class path in Jasper Suite?

Comment: Where did you find the jar?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dnf install mysql-connector-java
updatedb
locate mysql-connector-java.jar
```

Then simply add the absolute path in your JasperSoft "Driver Classpath" tab.

Answer (score 0):

As @pj409 mentioned, you have to add the driver.

main menu->file->new->jasperreport->next->next->Data adapater new

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7atKH.png)